# Using Proxy Settings with Nodejs for localhost

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, proxy, localhost

I have a nodejs application running using express on my localhost. I use bootstrap as well.
The problem is that at my workplace I have to use proxy settings. Once I type localhost:3000 it gets redirected to an IP address that does not run.
If I remove the proxy settings from Google Chrome localhost:3000 works some of the times but without the bootstrap styling.

I am also using routes to direct different urls to the corresponding ejs pages:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
  res.render('index', {});
});
```

The index.ejs file has a URL pointing to the bootstrap css online remote file.

Is there a way to have it running using the proxy as well.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try to just use `127.0.0.1:3000` instead `localhost:3000` at work

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work :( Thank you :)

Comment: So the problem is the remote file, why you need it to be remote? Can't you put it locally to your app? That's the way to go.

Comment: The problem is with any file even id it does not contain a reference to bootstrap. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use module http-proxy

```
npm install http-proxy
```

It is then possible to proxy requests by calling these functions

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

//
// Create your proxy server and set the target in the options.
//
httpProxy.createProxyServer({ target:'http://192.168.126.128:8080' }).listen(9000);
```

For more information visit
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy